# Image in JavaFX ListView

Tags: java, javafx

Is there anyway to add an image to a JavaFX ListView?

This is how I am currently setting the list view items.

```
private ListView<String> friends;
private ObservableList<String> items;
items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(getFriends);
friends.setItems(items);
```

I'm also using the list view value as an id to know which was selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a `ListCell` that displays the image and set a `cellFactory` on the `ListView`. The [standard oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm#CEGGEDBF) has an example of a custom list cell implementation.

You would do something along the following lines:

```
friends.setCellFactory(listView -> new ListCell<String>() {
    private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String friend, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(friend, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            Image image = getImageForFriend(friend);
            imageView.setImage(image);
            setText(friend);
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }
    }
});
```

The `updateItem(...)` method can be called quite often, so it is probably better to preload the images and make them available to the cell, rather than creating them every time `updateItem(...)` is called.

Comment: Thanks, i'm fairly new to JavaFX and i was struggling to work out how the cell factory worked.
This code works flawlessly :D

Answer (score 0):

remember to refresh or load your Listview 
with  **myListViewWithPath.setItems(myObserverFilledWithImages);**

```
@FXML
    private void browseButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("browseButton");
        DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        File file = chooser.showDialog(myStage);
        file = new File("E:\\FOLDER\\Imagen_File");

        if (file != null) {
            directoryField.setText(file.toString());
            oImage.setAll(load(file.toPath()));
        }
        imageFilesList.setItems(oImage); //this one load or refresh the ListView
    }
```