# JavaFx : How to put ImageView inside ListView

Tags: java, javafx

I've been searching some threads about JavaFx ListView still it's hard to look for a simple yet easy solution for putting a JavaFx ImageView inside JavaFx ListView. I am trying to create a chat application using JavaFx framework. at the photo it should look like that.This is not duplicate because the other thread is vague for a beginner like me. [ListView with imageview inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fyzn.png)

I tried something like this. I'm totally noob to this thanks in advance!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
     Image image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("bell.jpg"));
    ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "chocolate", "salmon", "gold", "coral", "darkorchid",
            "darkgoldenrod", "lightsalmon", "black", "rosybrown", "blue",
            "blueviolet", "brown");
   Image pic;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox box = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("ListViewSample");
        box.getChildren().addAll(list);
        VBox.setVgrow(list, Priority.ALWAYS);
        list.setItems(data);

        list.setCellFactory(listView -> new ListCell<String>() {
            public void updateItem(String friend, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(friend, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {

                    imageView.setImage(image);
                    setText(friend);
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }

        });

        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}`
```

Comment: this would do the job: listCell.setGraphic(row); where "row" is a HBox or GridPane...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image in JavaFX ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570803/image-in-javafx-listview)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You do not need to create a new HBox every time you want to set an image inside a ListView. You can directly use the `setCellFactory()` of the ListView to achieve the same result.

This example is just an extension of the answer [Image in JavaFX ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570803/image-in-javafx-listview)  and contains a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be tried and tested. *If you want to understand how this works, I suggest you to go through the linked question first.*

***Update*** - How to resize Images

To resize images to fit the size you want, make use of [fitWidth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#fitWidthProperty) and [fitHeight()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#fitHeightProperty) methods of the ImageView. There are other methods like [setSmooth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setSmooth-boolean-) and [setPreserveRatio()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setPreserveRatio-boolean-) which can come in handy as well.

***MCVE***

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewWithImages extends Application {

    private final Image IMAGE_RUBY  = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Ruby_logo_64x64.png");
    private final Image IMAGE_APPLE  = new Image("http://findicons.com/files/icons/832/social_and_web/64/apple.png");
    private final Image IMAGE_VISTA  = new Image("http://antaki.ca/bloom/img/windows_64x64.png");
    private final Image IMAGE_TWITTER = new Image("http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/fresh-social-media-icons-by-creative-nerds/png/64x64/twitter-bird.png");

    private Image[] listOfImages = {IMAGE_RUBY, IMAGE_APPLE, IMAGE_VISTA, IMAGE_TWITTER};

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();
        ObservableList<String> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList (
                "RUBY", "APPLE", "VISTA", "TWITTER");
        listView.setItems(items);

        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<String>() {
            private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String name, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(name, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    if(name.equals("RUBY"))
                        imageView.setImage(listOfImages[0]);
                    else if(name.equals("APPLE"))
                        imageView.setImage(listOfImages[1]);
                    else if(name.equals("VISTA"))
                        imageView.setImage(listOfImages[2]);
                    else if(name.equals("TWITTER"))
                        imageView.setImage(listOfImages[3]);
                    setText(name);
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        });
        VBox box = new VBox(listView);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

***OUTPUT***

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I need. I need to learn how to do it then implement it with the current project I am working. Thanks for the people that help me here I hope you guys keep on helping other people here!

Comment: well I wonder I am loading the images to my machine not in the web when I change it to something like this   Image image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("bell.jpg")); the image size is really big I wonder how I can resize it smaller.

Comment: You can leave it to the ImageView. Use [fitWidth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#fitWidthProperty) and [fitHeight()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#fitHeightProperty) on the ImageView. There are other methods like [setSmooth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setSmooth-boolean-) and [setPreserveRatio()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setPreserveRatio-boolean-) to help you.

Comment: @JustineMackay You can load the images from anywhere you like. I have used the web links because they can be copied and tried on any machine, whereas if I would have used the links local to my machine, you will have to make changes to the code to see it in action :)

Comment: setFitHeight and setFitWidth works like a charm! Thanks again!

Comment: Actually I am attempting to create a standalone application which is chat based Educational Module. I have used Java because I want it also to implement at Andriod. So the images must be at the local machine like if the user wants to change the picture they can load a new pic. Well thanks again you save me from so much time studying this issue ^^,

Comment: I already did, I think it has something to do with my internet connection when I reload it it doesn't accept. sorry about it >,<

Comment: imageView.resize(width, height); to resize image works for me.

Comment: Is it possible to do this keeping the radio button that shows what item is selected ? (CheckListView)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment I will show here some code, that is working for me:

```
private void setListEntry(ListCell<Label> listCell, Label label) {

        Image img = loadLableIcon(label);

        GridPane row = new GridPane();
        row.setHgap(15);
        row.setVgap(15);

        ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col1.setPercentWidth(90);
        ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col2.setPercentWidth(10);

        ImageView icon = new ImageView(img);

        javafx.scene.control.Label name = new javafx.scene.control.Label(label.getName());
        name.setMinWidth(120d);

        javafx.scene.control.Label amount = new javafx.scene.control.Label("" + label.getSize());

        HBox iconAndName = new HBox(10);
        iconAndName.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        iconAndName.getChildren().addAll(icon, name);

        row.add(iconAndName, 0, 0);
        row.add(amount, 1, 0);

        row.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1, col2);

        listCell.setGraphic(row);
    }
```

Please note: I'm not an expert in JavaFX, so I am not sure if it's best practise or not.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I am not also a expert in JavaFx but I'm trying to improve myself with programming. Can you update your code above with the whole code? I don't know how to implement it with a new code.