# How to add images to a enum class?

Tags: java, javafx

My code:

```
 public enum Rank{

//1.1 enum y filename
ACE(1, "resources/e1.png"),TWO(2, "resources/e2.png"),THREE(3, "resources/e3.png"),
FOUR(4, "resources/e4.png"),FIVE(5, "resources/e5.png"),SIX(6, "resources/e6.png"),
SEVEN(7, "resources/e7.png"),EIGHT(8, "resources/e8.png"), NINE(9, "resources/e9.png"),
TEN(10, "resources/e10.png"), JACK(11, "resources/e11.png"),QUEEN(12, "resources/e12.png"),
KING(13, "resources/e13.png");

private final int rankValue;
private final type? imageFile;

//1.2 constructor
private Rango(int rankValue, type? imageFile){
    this.rankValue= rankValue;
    this.imageFile= imageFile;
}
```

How can I get images be read in a method? What assigned type can read those image filepaths? Any advice please? Thanks.

Edit: is it possible to use Strings instead i.e. String imageFile and then use that type I'm missing to set it read the String filename?

Comment: You're starting to add a lot of complexity and entanglement to your enum. Instead, consider having a separate `ImageLoader` class and naming your resources like `card/ACE.png`.

Comment: nothing learned since your pevious question https://stackoverflow.com/q/61199559/203657 ?

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE:*** Changed to load JavaFX `Image` in the constructor, in order to not use Java 9 feature, and to cache the image instead of loading on every access.

You can access the file using [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

There are many articles on the web for how to use that, but something like this would work:

```
public enum Rank {

    ACE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7),
    EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13);

    private final int rankValue;
    private final Image image;

    private Rank(int rankValue) {
        this.rankValue = rankValue;
        String imageFile = "/resources/e" + rankValue + ".png";
        try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageFile)) {
            if (in == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Image not available for Rank." + name());
            this.image = new Image(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error loading image for Rank." + name(), e);
        }
    }

    public int getRankValue() {
        return this.rankValue;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }
}
```

If you don't want the file name to be derived from the `rankValue`, pass in `imageFile` as parameter instead.

Comment: I didn't understand what you did to the public byte[ ] getImage. I am using java 8 and I think I don't have it. Using maven archetype javafx. I don't manage to add this code working.

Comment: My guess is that for most use cases for an `enum`, it would be better to load the image data once (i.e. load it in the constructor and cache it in a field) than to reload it each time on demand. Since you have a fixed number of enums, and they're singletons, the memory trade-off is well controlled.

Comment: I found out what was best for this: Image img = new Image(myclass.class.getResources("resources/image.png").toExternalForm());
Now, packages in maven archetype must be the same as your project and then work in different project.packages instead all in one.