# Custom item in ListView JavaFX

Tags: java, image, listview, javafx

I have question about ListView in JavaFX.

How I can do custom item in ListView like this :

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8EO6.png)
[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8EO6.png)

Secondly, when I click Button1 i want to show image2 and textfield1

Comment: Set a custom cell factory and update the cells it returns from their `updateItem` methods. (Set suitable content to the the `graphic` property.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image in JavaFX ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570803/image-in-javafx-listview)

Comment: Okay, what if I want to have jpanel instead of image2 ?

Comment: Please read the official guide for cell factory from Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing your own `CellFactory` gives you all the options you want to apply on a `ListView`'s cell. Unfortunately the image you uploaded is not opening so I couldn't understand your exact requirements. anyway this is how you set your `CellFactory` for your `ListView` where `T` is your data type.

```
ListView#setCellFactory(Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> value)
```

**Example:**

```
ListView<Employee> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Employee>, ListCell<Employee>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Employee> call(ListView<Employee> param) {
        return new ListCell<Employee>() {
            
            private ImageView imageView = new ImageView("ImageURL");
            private TextField textField = new TextField("Text");
            private Button button = new Button("Button");
            private BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(imageView, null, button, null, textField);
            
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Employee item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.getName());
                    setGraphic(bp);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to have button, image view, textview on one item in Listview

Comment: don't recreate the controls on every call to updateItem (it's called reaaaally often)

Comment: I just wanted to give an example on how to use `graphic` property to include controls in the cell.

Comment: Thanks :) This is it :)

Comment: @kleopatra Give a good example on how to implement it instead of giving only negative feedback. Your way doesn't help the community.

Comment: nothing negative in pointing mistakes implemented in answers - anyway, looks like it helped you get it right after all <g>

Comment: actually, it's still not correct: missing the call to super which is mandatory

Comment: @kleopatra thank you for your feedback. I made the change.